# How to unify two ground term in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing a predicate in prolog:
calculate(Function,A,Value,Expr)
Function is a function may have variable A or not
Value is A 's value, and Expr is the expression of Function.

For example:

`calculate(2*3,x,2,E)`--return E=6.

`calculate(x+2,x,2,E)`--return E=4.

`calculate(2*(5+x*x),x,2,E)`--return E=18.

`calculate(x*(3+y*y),y,3,E)`--return E=x*12.

```
calculate(Function,A,Value,Expr):-
    A is Value, 
    %obviously, it is wrong, my question is how to unify these two guys.
    atom(A),
    num(Value),
    Expr is Function.
```

The above code can achieve example 1, which has no variable in function, but it can achieve when function has variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not passing in functions, you are passing in expressions, and the result is what they evaluate to. Since this is Prolog and we are free to do such things, I prefer to pass in one argument something like `x=2` rather than two arguments `x, 2` because I find it more readable. So the predicate I'm seeking is going to look more like `evaluate(+Expression, +Var=Value, ?Result)`.

What we should be doing here is induction on the shape of expressions. The base cases for expressions are thus variables and numbers, so let's handle those first:

```
evaluate(Num, _, Num) :- number(Num).
evaluate(Var, Var=Value, Value).
```

The first of these should be obvious: if I evaluate 3, I should get back 3, and I don't really care what the variable binding looks like to do so.

The second probably looks tautological, but the idea is, if I'm seeking the value of the variable `x` and I have a binding that looks like `x=3`, then the result is `3`.

Now you must do a bit of copy and paste. The nice thing is that you can easily here create functions that Prolog itself does not have built-in. The con is that it will be a bit repetitive.

```
evaluate(A*B, Binding, Value) :-
    evaluate(A, Binding, AValue),
    evaluate(B, Binding, BValue),
    Value is AValue * BValue.

evaluate(A+B, Binding, Value) :-
    evaluate(A, Binding, AValue),
    evaluate(B, Binding, BValue),
    Value is AValue + BValue.
```

So, the idea here is to *recur* down the left and right branches about an operator, and then apply that operator on those two sides. This little toy evaluator is going to work for very simple cases like this:

```
?- evaluate(2*(5+x*x), x=2, E).
E = 18
```

Now, you have a little complication here which is going to turn out to be quite annoying to handle properly, which is that what you want to do here is perform a kind of *partial* evaluation on the expression when you have multiple variables. The nasty example is this one:

```
?- evaluate(x*(3+y*y), y=3, E).
false.
```

You really want this to return `x*12`. Now there are two problems with the toy evaluator that are preventing this. The first is that it doesn't know what to do if you're looking for a variable and we don't have a binding for it, which we can solve by changing that base case:

```
evaluate(Var, X=Value, Result) :-
    atom(Var),
    (    Var = X -> 
         Result = Value 
    ; 
         Result = Var
    )
```

This will immediately lead to some errors though:

```
ERROR: Arithmetic: `x/0' is not a function
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] _3344 is x*3
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

The problem is that `is/2` demands that the right-hand side expression contain nothing but numbers and operators; it will never furnish you with a tree as a result. We can attempt to address this like so:

```
evaluate(A*B, Binding, Value) :-
    evaluate(A, Binding, AValue),
    evaluate(B, Binding, BValue),
    (number(AValue), number(BValue) ->
        Value is AValue * BValue
    ;
        Value = AValue * BValue
    ).
evaluate(A+B, Binding, Value) :-
    evaluate(A, Binding, AValue),
    evaluate(B, Binding, BValue),
    (number(AValue), number(BValue) ->
        Value is AValue + BValue
    ;
        Value = AValue + BValue
    ).
```

This at first appears to work:

```
?- evaluate(x*(3+y*y), y=3, E).
E = x*12 ;
false.
```

However, you will be able to find lots of cases where algebraic manipulations are not happening that would coalesce more of the constants:

```
?- evaluate(3*3*x*3*3, y=3, E).
E = 9*x*3*3 ;
```

The left constant factors are not going to fold in with the right constant factors because we don't have any tree rearranging code here. And the right constant factors have failed to combine for reasons that are more clearly illustrated by using `write_canonical/1`:

```
?- write_canonical(3*3*x*3*3).
*(*(*(*(3,3),x),3),3)
```

As you can probably guess from this, the innermost constants are folded together producing 9*x, which we then attempt to multiply by three. Because `9*x` is not a number, it won't fold together with `*3`. And now that you have a tree fragment on the left side, it won't fold together with the next `*3` either.

Addressing everything here in an ad-hoc way is going to be unpleasant but you could do it if you had to. To be honest, I have no idea how one would go about building a reasonably complete algebra system that could handle these things. I suspect you need a more potent data structure than the parse tree but beyond that I don't really know anything. Anyway, I hope this helps for now.

Comment: Can i use a subst function to replay Var with Val in Function?

Comment: Or, can i construct a predicate conBind(Var, Val, Binding)

Comment: @Jesse I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 1):

This needs more context. Looking at this, it feels like the *real* goal is to parse "functions" (arithmetic expressions with variables?) and simplify those.

Prolog gives you most of the parsing for free, in the sense that an expression like `2*x + 3` is also a valid Prolog term, and it even has the parse tree that you'd expect:

```
$ swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.1.3-31-g32d2d0a1d)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- T = 2*x + 3*y, display(T).
+(*(2,x),*(3,y))
T = 2*x+3*y.
```

So now you need to figure out two things:

1. How exactly is your language defined: what are the operators, the precedence, what is a value and what is a variable and so on.
2. How do you simplify?

The second point has the potential to give you most work. The problem you seem to be stuck on right now is relatively easy, but you need a different approach. You just have to traverse the tree and *replace* all occurrences of a "variable" (what you have in your second argument) with a value (what you have in your third argument). Then, you'd have to still simplify.

To see how to replace, you can try and read "The Art of Prolog", Chapter 3, "Recursive Programming". Around pages 70-80 there are even example programs that you can take almost as they are. There is also a fully worked out example of a program that does derivatives. It is not what you need but the approach is very close to what you probably need.

And a word of warning: when you say "function" or "variable" in the context of Prolog, they might mean different things to people in a Prolog mindset, so you will be talking past each other for a while. If you can put your question into language that is a bit more formal, it might be easier to help you with it.